# Heaviest loss of last four teams remaining in history of World Cup

Tags: football, trivia, statistics, world-cup

Brazil just lost 1-7 to Germany in 2014 World Cup. What is the biggest loss ever among the top 4 teams in a world cup (that is biggest lost in the semifinals, 3rd place match or the final match)? Did this game have the biggest margin of victory? What game had the most goals?

Comment: Margin of victory, not sure. Most goals, yes. I got an ESPN push notification saying "Germany scores most goals in a World Cup semifinal in 7-1 rout of Brazil...". :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brazil's defeat against Germany in World Cup 2014 semi-final is the heaviest loss of the last four teams remaining. This is tied with Sweden against Brazil (1-7) in 1950.

Other notable losses:

1930:

- Argentina beat USA 6-1 (first semi-final)
- Uruguay beat Yugoslavia 6-1 (second semi-final)

1950:

- Brazil beat Spain (6–1) (after beating Sweden 7-1)

1954:

- West Germany beat Austria 6-1 in second semi-final

Most goals in a match: In any semi-finals, this match has the most goals (8).
However, in the [1958 world cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup), there were 9 goals in the West Germany vs France (3-6) game.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup)

Comment: In 1982, there were 11 goals in the match Hungary v El Salvador. Hungary won 10–1.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw True but the question is for "heaviest loss of *last four teams remaining* in history of World Cup".

Comment: USA reached the semi-final in 1930?  Were there only four teams at the event?